# One Cookie - Multiple Pages

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using the following cookie:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){

   if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) 
   {
      var thirtyDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
      var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + thirtyDays);
      document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" + expires.toUTCString();
      $j.colorbox({ inline:true, href:"#gallery-nav-instruct"});
   }

});
```

Everything works fine with one exception. The above cookie is for displaying instructions the first time a user visit the gallery yet the gallery has multiple pages. What happens is the user sees the instructions for each page in the gallery the first time they visit that specific page. These instructions need to load only once when they visit the gallery no matter which page they start on. How do I go about changing this so it displays only once across my gallery pages?

Couple Notes:

The gallery is wrapped inside a Dreamweaver Template and the cookie is inside that template. I cannot move the cookie outside of the template for a few reasons.

Also I use a hosted CMS and I *DO NOT* have server side access so it must be done using javascript.

Comment: Put a flag as the cookie (true/false). You can check the cookie to see if the user has seen the instruction in this session.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add `;path=/` to make your cookie into a site cookie. See this article on [JavaScript Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for more details.

Comment: Using my above code can you give me an example as to where I add the `path=/` ?  I am not 100% sure as to where I add it.

Comment: You can just change `visited=true;expires=` to `visited=true;path=/;expires=`

Answer (score -1):

```
document.cookie = valuename + "=" + value + "; " + expires + ";domain=;path=/";
```

This `"domain=;path=/";` will take dynamic domain as its cookie will work in subdomain.
It will work if you want to test in localhost.