# Setting and checking a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a home page with a choice of 2 links. When one of those links is clicked I want to create a cookie so that all other internal pages remember this choice.

How do I set a cookie on one page and read the same cookie on different pages?

This is what I have:

```
// Home page on click event
function setRed() {
  document.cookie = "color=red; max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365; // 60 seconds to a minute, 60 minutes to an hour, 24 hours to a day, and 365 days.
};

//Internal Page Check
window.onload = checkCookie();

function checkCookie() {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("color") == "red") {
    document.body.id = "red"; 
  } else {
    document.body.id = "blue";
  };
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109437/one-cookie-multiple-pages) stackoverflow question.

Basically, when you say `document.cookie` make sure to add this to the end of it:

```
;path=/
```

Then call `checkCookie()`

This basically tells the browser to let the cookie be accessed anywhere across the site. However, as far as I know, if your two pages are hosted on different domains it is impossible for both of them to access the same cookie (due to security reasons.)

Also, the function you use to get the cookie looks incorrect. From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp):

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

You could then use this function in your `checkCookie()` function:

```
function checkCookie() {
  if (getCookie("color") == "red") {
    document.body.id = "red"; 
  } else {
    document.body.id = "blue";
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, works great now. Can you explain why the getCookie function was incorrect? I leaned that method on another stack overflow question and it did work for a single page setup, but not here...

Comment: @user500665 Try logging the value of `document.cookie`. It's a string, so if memory serves me right then it doesn't contain the function `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding path to your cookie so that all page within your site can access it.

```
// Home page on click event
function setRed() {
    // 60 seconds to a minute, 60 minutes to an hour, 24 hours to a day, and 365 days.
    document.cookie = "color=red; max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 +"; path=/"; 
};

//Internal Page Check
window.onload = checkCookie();

function checkCookie() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("color") == "red") {
        document.body.id = "red"; 
    } else {
        document.body.id = "blue";
    };
};
```