# jQuery Cookie glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I have an 'Accept Cookies' bar at the foot of my web page using the following HTML:

```
<div class="cookies-banner-bloc">
            <div class="cookies-banner-container">
                <p>We use cookies on this website.</p>
                <a class="cookies-close-button no-border">Close this Message</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I use the following jQuery to use cookies to store when the user has clicked 'Close', however, the cookie only seems to be stored on the one page and not across the entire site. I do have it in my `header.php` script so it should be affecting all my templates.

Why is this only working on one page?

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            if(getCookie("userclosedalert")=="true"){
                  $(".cookies-banner-bloc").addClass('hide');
                  removeClass = false;
            } else {
                  $(".cookies-banner-bloc").addClass('show');
                  removeClass = false;
            }
            $(".cookies-close-button").click(function () {
               document.cookie = "userclosedalert=true";

            });

        });

        </script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cookies-banner-bloc {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 25px 0;
    opacity: 1;
    display:none;
}

.cookies-banner-bloc.show {
    display:block;
}

.cookies-banner-bloc.show.hide,.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!

`document.cookie = "userclosedalert=true;path=/";`

Found this useful post: [One Cookie - Multiple Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109437/one-cookie-multiple-pages)

Answer (score 1):

I also do not see when your cookie expires. At the next session, the user will see this message again. You can use something like this

```
var x = 12 * 20; //or whatever offset
var CurrentDate = new Date();
CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth() + x);
document.cookie = "userclosedalert=true; expires=" + CurrentDate + ";path=/";
```